# qnx6 fs cannot be mounted read/write, standard hd

Tags: mount, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am running Neutrino 6.4.0 with an attached standard 2.5" , 250GB Toshiba hard disk with 6 pre-existing qnx6 partitions. All of them can be mounted read-only; however, I cannot mount any of those as read/write. For instance:

```
mount -r -t qnx6 /dev/hd1t77.3 /home/p3
```

works fine, while

```
mount -t qnx6 /dev/hd1t77.3 /home/p3
```

returns the following:

```
mount: Can't mount /home/p3 (type qnx6)
mount: Possible reason: Read-only file system
```

I have even tried different sync options (`-o sync=ignore` , and `-o sync=optional`), to no avail.

Interestingly, I have created an additional partition on the same disk using `mkqnx6fs /dev/hd1t77.6` , and that partition CAN be mounted read/write

My question is, what might be causing the existing partitions to be read-only, and is there any way to make them read-write?

Comment: Relevant to this: `mount -o sync=optional /dev/usb0 /home/hdd` worked for me (I know you said it didn't work for you)

Answer (score 1):

Your system defines partitions as qnx4 (t77). Probably you should try mount it with qnx4 type. See [official help](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Ffsystems_NFS.html&resultof=%22mount%22%20%22remote%22%20%22filesystem%22) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am sure the partitions are qnx6, and in any case trying to mount them as qnx4 fails with `Corrupted file system detected`. Bear in mind that mounting these partitions as qnx6, readonly results in them being perfectly readable

Comment: Some ideas:
1. try '-w' flag for mount,
2. mount as read and remount with flags '-wu'

Comment: Thanks again, but I had already tried both, with the same outcome. One angle I'm working now is trying to figure out what is different between the existing partitions, and the one I created with `mkqnx6fs` , given that the latter can be mounted as rw. However, I quickly found that fdisk gives me totally meaningless results; for instance, instead of showing the 6 partitions I have (and can mount) on the disk, it only shows 2 partitions: one marked 'non-QNX' type 114 , the other marked 'DOS' type 6. Now I'm lost!